# Lua 5.2: Update System (Need Help)

Tags: io, lua

i need help on FileEditing in Lua because i Just leant how to us it...

That's my CODE:

```
local clientFile, serverFile = io.open("client.txt", "r"), io.open("server.txt", "r")

local clientVer, serverVer = tostring(clientFile:read()), tostring(serverFile:read())

io.write("\nCurrent Version: "..clientVer.."\nLast Version: "..serverVer.."\n\n")

if clientVer == serverVer then
    io.write("No Updates for now.\n\n")
elseif clientVer ~= serverVer then
    io.write("Updating...\n\n")
    os.remove("client.txt")
    local clientFileW = io.open("client.txt", "w+")
    clientFileW:write(serverVer)
    local clientFileR = io.open("client.txt", "r")
    io.write("Client Updated!\n\n")
    io.write("Current Version: "..tostring(clientFileR:read()).."\nLast Version: "..serverVer.."\n\n")
end
```

That's my Output when i have the Same Versions in Client-Server:

```
Current Version: v2
Last Version: v2

No Updates for now.
```

AND that's my Output when i have foe Example Client: v1 and Server: v8

```
Current Version: v1
Last Version: v8

Updating...

Client Updated!

Current Version: nil
Last Version: v8
```

WHY do i have that nil ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the output is being buffered (i.e. not being written to the file right away). This buffering is done by the [C library functions which Lua uses for IO](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/liolib.c.html).  Here is a walk-through of what is happening in your code:

```
    -- ...
    -- new, empty file is created
    local clientFileW = io.open("client.txt", "w+")
    -- server version is stored in an internal buffer, waiting to be written to
    -- the file
    clientFileW:write(serverVer)
    local clientFileR = io.open("client.txt", "r")
    -- the empty client.txt is opened
    io.write("Client Updated!\n\n")
    -- since the client.txt file is empty, nil is returned by clientFileR:read()
    io.write("Current Version: "..tostring(clientFileR:read())
             .."\nLast Version: "..serverVer.."\n\n")
end
-- end of program execution, flush buffers (e.g. write the new version),
-- close files, etc.
```

To solve your program, you can add a call to [`:flush()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-file:flush) after you write the new client version. This will force the internal buffer to be written to the file at that point:

```
-- ...
local clientFileW = io.open("client.txt", "w+")
clientFileW:write(serverVer)
clientFileW:flush()
local clientFileR = io.open("client.txt", "r")
-- ...
```